# Rotating Camera Around Self, limiting rotation angle in ThreeJS

Tags: camera, rotation, three.js, mousecapture

I am using Three.JS to create a scene.

I want to be able to set my camera in the corner of a room and have the viewer rotate the camera around on the spot, without moving the camera's position.

Also, I want to limit the span of rotation (so that they cannot rotate the camera to look behind them).

I found `FirstPersonControls`, but I want the user to have to click and drag to rotate the view.

I know of the [minecraft example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_minecraft.html), but it doesn't do the click and drag or angle restriction.
Does anyone know of any other existing examples that accomplish something similar? Thanks.

Comment: FirstPersonControls should be pretty commented and self explanatory if i remember correctly. What is preventing you of adding this functionality yourself? Three.js is still 3d programming, you probably wont be able to find a readymade script out there for every single idea that you might have. On the other hand, three is so friendly that it's easy to do an extension like this.

Comment: @pailhead, I was unsure how to start as I am new to Three.JS and javascript in general. However I found an example [here](http://360.art.pl/experimental/1/) which I found useful and will hopefully help to implement this.